# Amazon Fee not showing on MWS Orders API

Tags: amazon-mws

we have integrated with Amazon's API http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/  and the results look great, 
But it is not showing us the Amazon Fee value. How do we get that number in the results? 
We can see all other amounts such as taxes, discounts etc but not the fee charged by Amazon to sell the item.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fees are found in the [Finances API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/index.html).  Look at the various [financial datatypes](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/finances/Finances_Datatypes.html) to find the fees you're looking for.  I believe this is a fairly new API.  We started pulling our fees out of here a couple months ago.